# Ruby boolean methods

Tags: ruby

I have a method I wish to use, to be make my code a little more legible (in my opinion)

My code:

```
def format_chosen_address(address)
  # Add country before the postcode
  postcode = address.split("\n").last
  country = postcode.is_welsh? ? 'WALES' : 'ENGLAND'
  address.split("\n").insert(-2, country).join(' ')
end


def is_welsh?
    welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
    welsh_postcodes.include? self
end
```

I get the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_welsh?' for "SA1 6AZ":String
```

Where have I gone wrong because thought self and boolean methods could be used this way?

I can get it to work if I do the following, but it doesn't read as nice to me.

```
def format_chosen_address(address)
  # Add country before the postcode
  postcode = address.split("\n").last
  country = is_welsh?(postcode) ? 'WALES' : 'ENGLAND'
  address.split("\n").insert(-2, country).join(' ')
end

def is_welsh?(postcode
  welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
  welsh_postcodes.include? postcode
end
```

Comment: The `is_welsh?` method will only work like that if you define it inside the `String` class

Comment: Of course!! Thank you

Comment: In Ruby you usually avoid `is_` or `has_` prefixes for predicate methods.

Comment: When you have a method that you would like to call on something such as `postal_code.welsh?` postal code starts looking less and less like a primitive string and more like it's own class of thing, so even if consideration determines "not worth it's own class" it's at least worth that consideration; a postal code class may be too specific but you might see other classes that make sense and, say,  promote address (there's a lot of functionality for address in here, as well) instead of the specific postal code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `postcode.is_welsh?` which means you are calling the method `is_welsh?` on the string, but you didn't define the method on String but within another class.

Actually, I advise adding methods like to the String class. It is too specific to pollute the whole String namespace. Instead, I suggest just leaving that method as a (probably as a `private`) helper method and passing the postal code string to it as an argument:

```
def is_welsh?(postcode)
  welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
  welsh_postcodes.include? postcode
end
```

and call it like:

```
country = is_welsh?(postcode) ? 'WALES' : 'ENGLAND'
```

Comment: 100% I don't want to be adding to the String xlass for something so small

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `is_welsh?` inside the String class like this:

```
class String
  def is_welsh?
    welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
    welsh_postcodes.include? self
  end
end
```

But it doesn't really make sense for every String to have a method that tells if it's Welsh or not. So the better option is to make it a method that takes a parameter (like your second example in the question):

```
def is_welsh?(postcode)
  welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
  welsh_postcodes.include? postcode
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a module to add certain helpers to the singleton class of the string. Meaning that they are only added for that specific instance of `String` and not for all strings.

```
module PostcodeHelpers
  def is_welsh?
    welsh_postcodes = ['SA1 6AZ', 'SA7 9BR', 'CF10 1AX']
    welsh_postcodes.include?(self)
  end

  def country
    is_welsh? ? 'WALES' : 'ENGLAND'
  end
end

def format_chosen_address(address)
  *lines, postcode = address_lines(address)
  [*lines, postcode.country, postcode].join(' ')
end

private # assuming you are in class or module context

def address_lines(address)
  *lines, postcode = address.split("\n")

  # Default to empty string since you don't want to extend nil by accident.
  postcode ||= ''
  postcode.extend(PostcodeHelpers)

  [*lines, postcode]
end
```

Like you can see this might be overkill for this scenario and produces quite a bit of additional code.